# What is the correct way to add the aria-label to mat-progress-bar in angular material 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am creating a progress bar using angular material version 8 and want to add aria-label to it so when i hover on it, it's shows the value and description for the progress bar

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `matTooltip` to see the value and description.

Give this a try:

```
<mat-progress-bar 
  name="label"
  mode="determinate" 
  [value]="value"
  attr.aria-label="Progress - {{ value }} %"
  matTooltip="Progress - {{ value }} %">
</mat-progress-bar>
```

And in your Component Class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Determinate progress-bar
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'progress-bar-determinate-example',
  templateUrl: 'progress-bar-determinate-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['progress-bar-determinate-example.css'],
})
export class ProgressBarDeterminateExample {
  value = 0;
  intervalId;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.value < 100) this.value = this.value + 20;
    }, 5000);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with only the matTooltip is the aria-label attribute is helpful for another reason ?